# BASH: start gFTP with specific size/maximized

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to build a closed loop ftp client, currently using slax.

The idea is that the user follows a menu to choose a site and then the system starts gFTP full screen (1024x768 or 1280x1024) and when this exits it closes X windows and logs off.

Now all I need is making gFTP start with a prescribed size and its done.

I've tried to compile wmctrl to test this but my slax build has an issue with glib headers not matching the library version.

---

**UPDATE:**

A great couple of suggestions, its such a shame that gFTP does not support -geometry option.

I was hoping it would and guessing with no WM (just X) that wmctrl wouldn't have anything to talk to, so wont work either.

Unless there's any other suggestions I think it might be game over :(

Thanks for your suggestions so far, great community spirit here!

---

PS...

Just had a thought, if anybody knows a way to strip KDE right down to nothing so that the application is the onlything on the screen then we may be onto something :)

If its easier with gnome then so be it - i'll grab a new copy of slax.
The only reason I want slax is that its very light so good for a VM. My other servers are Gentoo and CentOS but thats off topic :S

Just to clarify; there will only be one copy gFTP window open ever, when you exit it (status 0 or otherwise) I want X11 to close and logout. I dont want any widgity grubs for the users to play with! So no clock, panel, menu. Geez I sound like the BOFH. Hmmmmmmmm...

The login details for gFTP remote site will come from a TUI menu before X11 starts.

Answer (score 1):

Get wmctrl and start gFTP like this:

```
gftp && wmctrl -r "gFTP" -b toggle,fullscreen
```

It will run gftp and maximize it to a point where the window title is hidden.

Comment: If there are multiple gFTP windows or it takes unexpectedly long to open, this is not so good...

Comment: Quoting the author: "when this exits it closes X windows and logs off"

Answer (score 0):

If you are using KDE, KWin allows you to configure application- and window-specific rules.  Just launch gFTP, right-click on the title bar, find the "Window-specific settings" entry, check "Fullscreen: Force", and save.  You can also use [`kstart --fullscreen gFTP`](http://docs.kde.org/stable/en/kdebase-runtime/userguide/windows-how-to-work.html).

In Gnome, you can use the add-on program [Devil's Pie](http://live.gnome.org/DevilsPie) for the same functionality as KWin's built-in window matching rules.

Many X programs accept a `-geometry WxH+X+Y` argument, which means "window sized WxH at position (X,Y)".  If you are running without a window manager, and gFTP supports this switch, this will be your best option.

---

#### [Edit]

Given your updated description, it sounds like you really just want a full-screen window manager.  [Matchbox](http://matchbox-project.org/) is a lightweight and highly-customizable fullscreen window manager, and would be much better suited for this task than any of Gnome's or KDE's full-featured window managers.

Comment: Unfortunately, gFTP does not support the -geometry option